# Insert operation is failing in map container in C++

Tags: c++

My code is very complex to put it over here. I will just try to explain how I am performing map operations.

### connection.h

```
struct mAttributeTable_Compare
{
bool operator()(char* s1, char* s2) const
{
    return (strcmp(s1,s2) < 0);
}
};
typedef struct
{
  map<Char*, Attribute*, mAttributeTable_Compare> mAttributeTable_API;
  map<Char*, Attribute*, mAttributeTable_Compare>::iterator iter_API;      

} Connection_vars;
class Attribute
{
    protected:
           Attribute(char*);

    public:
        Void            AddValue(Char* value);
        Char*           GetName();
        Char*           GetValue(Int index = 0); 

    private:
        Char*   mName;
        vector<Char*>   mValues;      
        Int     mType;
        Int     mCount;
};
class Connection
{
   public:
    Connection();
   Protected:
    Void  ProcessAttribute(int,Attribute*);
   private:
    map<Char*, Attribute*, mAttributeTable_Compare> mAttributeTable;
    map<Char*, Attribute*, mAttributeTable_Compare>::iterator iter;      
    void *mConnVars;
};
```

### connection.cpp

```
#include "connection.h"
Connection()
{
    mConnVars = (Connection_vars *)calloc(1, sizeof(Connection_vars));  
    if(!mConnVars)                                                      
    {                                                                   
      return;                                                           
    }                                                                   

}
Void Connection::ProcessAttribute(int attrName, Attribute* attribute )
{
 Attribute* attr_API;
 Connection_vars *my_ConnectionVars = (Connection_vars *)mConnVars;
 if ( attrName == 10 )
 {
  attr_API = new Attribute("TraceOutput");
  Char* fileName = (Char*)attribute->GetValue(0);
  attr_API->AddValue(filename);

  /* this map variable insert operation is working*/ 
  mAttributeTable.insert(pair<Char*, Attribute*>(attr_API->GetName(), attr_API);

  /* But the below operation is returning a SEGMENTATION FAULT*/
  (my_ConnectionVars ->mAttributeTable_API).insert(pair<Char*, Attribute*>(attr_API->GetName(), attr_API);


}
Attribute::Attribute(Char* name)
{ 
    mName = strdup(name);
    mType = 0; 
    mCount = 0;
}

Char* Attribute::GetName()
{
    return mName;
}

Char* Attribute::GetValue(Int index)                        
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < (Int)mValues.size())
        return mValues[index];
    else
        return NULL;
}
Void Attribute::AddValue(Char* value)
{
    Char* temp = (Char*)strdup(value);              

    mValues.push_back(temp);
    mCount++;
}
```

Inside ProcessAttribute() above, I am not able to insert into the map container(mAttributeTable_API) declared in the structure(Connection_vars) from header and getting a SEGMENTATION FAULT, where as I could able to insert into the map container(mAttributeTable) declared as private variable inside the class(Connection). I am not able to find the reason where I am going wrong. Please help me in fixing this. Any kind help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each one of those asterisks is like a shruiken thrown at my eyes.

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: Where's your [testcase](http://sscee.org)?

Comment: Heard about "const-correctness"? I think I don't see any `char*` (erm, "`Char*`") in your code that shouldn't be `const char*` rather...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the following line:

```
mConnVars = (Connection_vars *)calloc(1, sizeof(Connection_vars));
```

wil not initialize the std::maps inside the Connection_vars struct correctly. 
It will only allocate the memory and initialize them with zero's.

Maybe it helps to replace above line with:

```
mConnVars = new Connection_vars;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Inside ProcessAttribute() above, I am not able to insert into the map
>   container(mAttributeTable_API)

'Void' does not name a type.

Ship it!

Comment: Maybe it's just a `typedef void Void;`. However I see another one: `Protected` is not a C++ keyword (but maybe a `#define Protected protected`? (illegal btw))

Comment: Sorry to remind you again, I did not pasted all of my code here. Yes, as you said they are typedefs only. Every thing else is working fine, except map container insertion operations. Please tell me where might I have gone in wrong in using map.Thanks !

Comment: You forgot to typedef the map?

Comment: @ybc Enigma answered you just below... (7stud totally irrelevant, if it were the case there would be a compile-time error, not a segfault)